# Split extension of groups and semidirect product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra, semidirect-product

I am studing Ext functor and have some basic problem.

For every semidirect product $G$ of groups $N$ and $H$, short exact sequence $0 \to N \to G \to H  \to 0$ splits.

On the other hand, every short exact sequence which splits is a neutral element in Baer sum.

This means that for every $G$ which is semidirect product, sequence $0 \to N \to G \to H \to 0$ is equivalent to sequence $0 \to N \to N\times H\to H \to 0$.

In particular, $G \cong N\times H$, which of course don't have to be true (we can take abelian groups $N$ and $H$ and $G$ don't have to be abelian).

Where is the mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: The sentence beginning "This means that" is not true.

Comment: Thank you. So every short exact sequence which splits is neutral element in Baer sum, but this sum is not defined up to equivalence of sequences? When we can say in Baer sum, that two sequences are the same element?

Comment: What Baer sum are you talking about if you are not restricting to an abelian category?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about Baer sum in an abelian category ( actually category of R-modules). That explains a lot. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: I read your post carefully, and it looks like you mention the Baer sum at the very beginning. So let me try to explain two different things.

1. The Yoneda $\operatorname{Ext}^1$ is defined as **the equivalence classes** of extensions. Two extensions
   $$\tag{*} 0 \to B\to C\to A \to 0$$
   and
   $$\tag{**} 0 \to B\to C'\to A \to 0$$
   are equivalent if there exists a morphism $\phi\colon C\to C'$ that makes part of a commutative diagram with exact lines (*) and (**) and identity morphisms $id\colon B\to B$ and $id\colon A\to A$. Note that by the five-lemma, such a morphism $\phi$ is necessarily an isomorphism (and this observation shows that this is indeed a symmetric relation, while it is clearly reflexive and transitive).

   Since semi-direct product is not usually isomorphic to the direct product, the arrow $\phi$ simply can't exist and you don't get isomorphic extensions.

   Note that short exact sequences and the five-lemma still make sense for non-abelian groups (so you can take the same definition for the equivalence of extensions)... *but the Baer sum doesn't*!
2. Baer sum *for exact sequences in an abelian category* is defined as a certain construction on short exact sequences, *and then* one verifies that the construction does not depend on the equivalence relation. The zero element is the equivalence class of the extension $0 \to B\to B\oplus A\to A\to 0$. A good reference where the Yoneda's $\operatorname{Ext}^1$ with the Baer sum is constructed is Mac Lane's "Homology". The assumption that your category is abelian (e.g. that your exact sequences are formed by abelian groups) is crucial for the construction.

Comment: It feels like this answer glosses over a major issue here which is that once you have semidirect products, you are no longer in an abelian category.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft The category of non-abelian groups still has notion of short exact sequences and the five-lemma holds, so it is possible to consider equivalence classes of extensions. What is not possible is to define the Baer sum.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft I actually overlooked the mention of the Baer sum in the original post, I saw it only in the comments... I edited the answer to make it potentially helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. I mixed seqences of modules and sequences of groups.

Comment: For a given action of a group $H$ on an abelian group $A$, the second cohomology group $H^2(G,A)$ corresponds to equivalence classes of extensions of $A$ by $H$ that induce the specified action by conjugation, where the zero element corresponds to the split extension. Given two such extensions,we can define their Baer sum, which another such extension, and this operation corresponds to addition in $H^2(H,M)$. So I am not agreeing with your statement that it is not possible to define the Baer sum on nonabelian extensions.

Comment: @Derek Holt Do people still call that thing "Baer sum"? Also, in the abelian setting, Baer sum makes sense for $\operatorname{Ext}^n$ for any $n$.